# How is the upcoming 'dynamic' keyword in .net 4.0 going to make my life better?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I don't quite get what it's going to let me do (or get away with :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two big areas are:

- working with COM assemblies where methods return vague types - so you can essentially use late binding
- working with DLR types

Other uses include things like:

- duck-typing where there is no interface
- Silverlight talking to the host page's DOM
- talking to an xml file.

In C# itself, this allows a few things, such as a basic approach to generic operators:

```
static T Add<T>(T arg1, T arg2) { // doesn't work in CTP
     return ((dynamic)arg1) + ((dynamic)arg2);
}
```

(of course, I'd argue that [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) is a better (more efficient) answer to this)

Comment: I found this a nice example in addition to your last link: http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2009/02/05/simulating-inumeric-with-dynamic-in-c-4-0.aspx, though I wonder what the performance impact would be.

Comment: @Razzie - indeed, I have a test harness ready to go as soon as the CTP includes the new bits ;-p

Answer (score 5):

From Charlie Calvert's blog:

> Useful Scenarios
>
> There are three primary scenarios that will be enabled by the new support for dynamic lookup:
>
> 1. Office automation and other COM Interop scenarios
> 2. Consuming types written in dynamic languages
> 3. Enhanced support for reflection

Read more here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/01/25/future-focus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are some podcasts about the feature itself and how it can be used:

- [Inside C# 4.0: dynamic typing, optional parameters, covariance and contravariance](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Inside-C-40-dynamic-type-optional-parameters-more-COM-friendly/)
- [C# 4.0 New Features - COM Interop Enhancements](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/mike+ormond/C-40-New-Features-COM-Interop-Enhancements/)
- [deCast - Dynamic Xml with C# 4.0](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/RobBagby/deCast-Dynamic-Xml-with-C-40/) "will illustrate how you can take advantage of the dynamic functionality enabled in C# 4.0 to access Xml data in a more natural way"